# Poor Upload performance on symmetric FTTP 100/100Mbps link

Tags: networking, internet-connection, upload, packet-loss, fiber

I know what I'm suffering is a "first-world" problem...I have it good, but not as good as it should be.  [Moving here at the suggestion of the moderator in SE Network Engineering.]

tl;dr; - I have 100/100 FTTP service but uploads are painfully slow. I've gathered lots of data (see below), but what issue does it indicate?  What else can I do to expose the root cause?

I'm hoping someone can give me some inspiration. I've done a lot of testing/diagnosis, but I'm not a network engineer so I'll share as much detail as possible (first in the hope that you can help me, second in the hope that it helps others observing similar issues).

Short version: I've just been connected to a FTTP service that should (they claim) give me 100/100 symmetric. speedtest.net (classic/flash), Ookla iOS, Ookla Android and speedtest-cli all show 100/100 consistently.
My experience with general DOWNLOADS and downstream internet access via other protocols follow these results.

The problems is UPLOADS are virtually unusable for anything practical.

Here's the list of symptoms. [tests carried out on ethernet direct to the router using Win7, Win10 and RPi plus Macbook Pro on 5Ghz Wifi - the local connection is NOT the issue]

1. http://beta.speedtest.net (HTML5/WebSockets) typically gives
   100/2 (yes two!!) Mbps
2. Google speed tester (HTML5/WebSockets) show 100/2 Mbps

   - Both of the above will only use a max of 4 web sockets - speedtest classic and cli both create 8 or more TCP connections if download performance is good.  I know one other subscriber who gets similar results on these basic tests.
   - both these tests show a brief spike in performance at the beginning of the test.
3. Uploading 15Mb files to AWS S3 via CLI - max of about 150kbps, often stalls/fails (uploading from the same devices via 17/1Mpbs ADSL2 or 4G tethered) gives reliable 3-500kbps).

   - Uploading a 1-2Mb file with AWS CLI will usually works at about 150kbps (i.e. AGAIN there is a quick burst of throughput on smaller uploads)
   - uploading from AWS CLI from Azure hosted M to S3 give very fast performance (no throttling at the AWS end).
   - Configuring AWS CLI to do multipart uploads has no beneficial effect (smallest chunksize is 5Mb and that seems to be too big for reliable
4. Upload to AWS S3 via AWS web console - never works - times out.
5. Upload files to a Azure or AWS VM via SCP or SFTP (using bash, WinSCP or filezilla) gives about 125 kbps. (SCP from AWS to Azure and vice versa gives very fast performance - no throttling on AWS / Azure in either direction)
6. iPerf tests with server hosted on the premises, OR with server hosted on AWS EC2 VM (client on prem) OR with 3rd party iPerf server hosted at speedtest.serverius.net:5002

   - ALL of these give consistent results as follows
   - Downstream TCP connections (downloads or pushes to my network) - a single TCP stream will hit about 60-70Mbps and 2 or more streams will max out the 100Mpbs :thumbsup:
   - Upstream TCP connections (uploads or pulls from my network) - a single TCP stream will hit about 3-5Mbps.  Running multiple streams is roughly directly proportional
   - 10 parallel TCP streams will give about 40Mpbs and 25-30 Streams will max out the connection.
   - Adjusting TCP window sizes makes no [positive] difference
   - UDP throughput will go up to 100Mbps in both directions.
7. Running wireshark captures for uploads show high numbers of duplicate ACKs with 20-30 duplicates for many packets.  I'm not qualified to determine whether this is "definitely bad" or "potentially normal", but googling finds multiple references to multiple DUP ACKs indicating dropped packets and possible interface negotiation issues.
8. I know the providers backhaul is Virgin Media Business. My router/ONT shows my connection to them is 1000Gbps full duplex and I see reliable sub 5ms ping to the first hop on the virgin network.

   - traceroute shows that there is only a single hop controlled by the provider (presumably their fiber switch) before traffic hits Virgin hosts.
9. The provider has not confirmed whether they can repeat these tests on other connection or their own network.   I now know of one other subscriber seeing the most obvious issue (google speed) but have not asked them to test further yet.
10. I have given them all this data, offered any help they need to diagnose, and they have been proactive including contacting Ookla to check the difference between speedtest.net classic and beta [ironically they said they were "the same" when I can see from the network conversation traces that they are clearly different]
11. They have tested my fiber and offered to change the router.  Based on my results, this seems unlikely to be the issue, but I will let them do this to eliminate another possible cause.
12. No doubt most of the provider's residential customers trust the 100/100 numbers they see from Ookla.  They will be very happy with browser downloads, streaming etc. and will probably tolerate slow uploads to GDrive, Gmail, Email services, etc because they are better than the dodgy rural ADSL2 option from BT/OpenReach.
13. The ONT/Router is a Genexsys DRG739v2 running DRGOS 1.13.3 (I can't     update this, it's under the providers control).

When working from home in a technology role I need to upload/send data frequently, reliably and (hopefully) speedily too.  This FTTP connection is both unreliable for certain services/protocols AND slower than my ASDL2 or 4G for those same services/protocols.  Can you tell I'm deparate to find a resolution??  :-)

Sooooo... to the questions:

1. Does anyone recognise these symptoms and have any suggestions for resolution that I can pass to the provider????

[I appreciate there are MANY factors from HW to interface config, to packet shaping, QoS and who knows what else, but it seems crazy that this result in an UNUSABLE connection]

2. Is this likely to be a mis-negotiated interface?... would that result in a connection where parallel TCP streams can achieved full throughput or does that mean someone is doing something deliberately (shaping/throttling)???
3. Would you expect to see the brief burst of throughput (perhaps 1-2Mb of transfer) at the beginning of a connection if there was a mis-negotiated interface?  Would you expect to see this if there were packet shaping?
4. Is this likely to be Virgin Media Business shaping traffic rather than my ISP, who says they don't apply any limits???  I've found little detail about Virgin business service, and of course I am not their customer (directly).
5. Is this likely to be Virgin Media Business connectivity/configuration issues???  Are they any good a configuring a network, validating it and monitoring it??
6. What else can I do to help the provider diagnose this and resolve it?

I've spent hours (probably days) of my time trying to eliminate variables like my network, my devices, my other service providers, as well as understand the differences between speedtest clients that give different results and gather as much data as possible. Ultimately I want to the provider to be successful, so I've invested my time to try and help them get to the bottom of this.  They have not denied the issue and been helpful so far in spite of not resolving this after 2 weeks of investigation.  I'm hopeful they will work to resolve this but I want to make it as easy/obvious for them as possible.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions and advice.

EDIT: 
1) The issue was initially resolved by finally persuading the ISP to switch my connection to a new port on their switch/router.  Being a small ISP, they were able to do this while I was on the phone and it immediately give me symmetric 100/100Mbs by most tests.
2) The good news did not last long, intermittent issues caused VPN and VOIP instability - after providing yet more data, they finally trace this to their network management software (which was throttling my 1Gbps base connection down to the 100/100 subscription). They turn it off and I enjoyed 800+Mbps symmetric for a few months until they resolved it.

Comment: My first thought: MTU size. Could be your connection is tunnelled somewhere and 1500 bytes packets can't get through. Lower the MTU of your local ethernet port to, say, 1400 at first, see if that helps. Then increase until you start having problems again, then back off again.

Comment: Thanks JvO - had not tried that.  I tried dropping it in increments all the way down to 1100 but no positive change.  even tried increasing it for giggles and little change there too. 
One more data point 
- if I switch to iPerf3 -Z (zero-copy) i see really good upload speeds with zero retries and a Cwnd of 358Kbytes.  
- Without zero-copy I get up to 20 retries per secon and a Cwnd of 10-5Kbytes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iPerf, so can't comment on that. By the way, what happens if you download from a remote IP address to your local one (i.e. reverse the data connection)?

Comment: Downloads, and reverse uploads, are fine - i.e. I can move data into my local network (via SSH/SCP/HTTP, etc) without issue.   My issue is that I can't move data OUT of my network via a single socket with any reliability or speed.

Comment: Should have been explicit - reverse downloads (remote host downloading from my local network via a forwarded port) have the same issue as uploads.

Comment: Who is your provider and can you please provide a traceroute from your network to www.linx.net